# jQuery ajax overwrite data/url beforeSend on specific url

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

## Question

I wanna set a ajax setting for global ajax handled by jQuery

#### Condition:

If ajax url is 'www.example.com', the data (querystring or body) will append token.

---

I tried two method

#### .ajaxPrefilter

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {

    // Add data to ajax option
    if (options.url.match(/www\.example\.com/i) !== null) {
        originalOptions.data.token = 'i_am_token'
    }

});
```

To add token when url is www.example.com-> it not work!

In console/debugger originalOptions Object is added token property, 
but request sent not having token parameter

#### .ajaxSetup / beforeSend Event

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {

        // Only GET Method
        if (settings.url.match(/www\.example\.com/i) == null){
            settings.url.replace(/((\.\/[a-z][0-9])*\?+[=%&a-z0-9]*)&?token=[a-z0-9]*&?([=%&a-z0-9]*)/gi, "$1$3")
        }

    },
    data: {
        token: 'i_am_token'
    }
});
```

And a reverse resolution, add token for each ajax request.

Same as last one, settings.url changed by string replace in the console/debugger.
But request still sent original url.

---

Test in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qVLN2/2/

Thanks for your reading and help :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should notice that the [String.replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function doesn't affect the original string!

You can try using `settings.url = settings.url.replace(....);` in your code.